# Add object to MySQL Result row (RowDataPacket) in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

I need to add an additional field to the mysql result object before send it to front end. (In my case it's .ejs)

This is my mysql result row:

```
RowDataPacket{ agent_id: 1,name: 'John', email: 'johndoe@gmail.com', mobile: 000000 }
```

I need to add: `{'Key': 'value'}` to this mysql row object?

Answer (score 0):

The following method worked for me. Hope this would help someone.

```
          for(var o = 0;o < rows.length;o++){
                var j = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows[o]));
                var names = Object.keys(j);
                var vals = Object.keys(j).map(function(_) { return j[_]; });
                names.push('Key');
                vals.push('Value');
                var jObj = {};
                names.forEach(function(k,i){
                    jObj[k] = vals[i];
                });
                console.log(jObj);
            }
```

Comment: I wonder whether a deep clone is necessary. Are you sure the edits can't be made on the original object?

Comment: @obfish I'm not quite sure whether deep clone is necessary. But I couldn't push values to the original object.

Comment: If you are sure the `RowDataPacket` is flat(i guess MySQL data is), you could try `Object.assign({'Key': 'value'}, rawDataPack)`. I didn't have a benchmark, but I believe it should be much faster.